# Return 2 specific columns from a Pandas DataFrame that uses filter_by

Tags: python, pandas

Below is just a portion of my code to understand my question. I'm filtering some data with conditions but I only want to return or basically print columns 'Site' and 'Date'. Seems so simple but I cannot figure it out. I do need these 2 column names and data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df.rename(columns={'UnitId': 'Site', 'StartTime': 'Date', 'IsFree': 'Open', 'IsWalkin': 'FF'}, inplace=True)
    filter_by = ['Site', 'Date', 'Open', 'FF']
    df = df.filter(items=filter_by)
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: datetime.fromisoformat(d).strftime("%m-%d %A "))
    df = df[df['Open']]
    df = df[~df['FF']]
    df['Site'] = df['Site'].replace([5095], '81')
    df['Site'] = df['Site'].replace([5096], '82')
    df['Site'] = df['Site'].replace([5097], '83')
    df['Site'] = df['Site'].replace([5098], '84')
    df['Site'] = df['Site'].replace([5099], '85')
    df['Open'] = df['Open'].replace([True], 'Y')
    df['FF'] = df['FF'].replace([False], 'N')
    return tabulate(df, headers=filter_by)
```

Comment: Kindly add a bit of context to the filtering that you are trying to achieve based out of the 2 columns you mentioned

Comment: `return df[filter_by]` ?

Comment: If  I the filter_by and just select the columns I want it remove my 2 conditions which are Open is True and FF is false.
df = df[df['Open']]
df = df[~df['FF']]

Comment: I'm sure there is a better way but I used del df['column_name'] to remove the columns I did not want to print which seems to work ok.